# Flags returned by OSVERSIONINFOEX.wSuiteMask

Tags: windows, native, winapi

Does anybody know what the following constants (defined in `WinNT.h`) mean?

```
#define VER_SUITE_COMMUNICATIONS            0x00000008
#define VER_SUITE_EMBEDDED_RESTRICTED       0x00000800
#define VER_SUITE_SECURITY_APPLIANCE        0x00001000
```

The values are returned in the `wSuiteMask` field of the `OSVERSIONINFOEX` struct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The suite mask is part of the operating system version. The complete list of suite mask constants, along with some explanation, is [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd419805.aspx). It indicates whether the version of Windows being run is an Enterprise edition, Data Center edition, home edition, etc.

`VER_SUITE_COMMUNICATIONS` = This is a version of Microsoft Office Communications Server

`VER_SUITE_EMBEDDED_RESTRICTED` = Embedded Windows (I'm not sure what the `RESTRICTED` indicates)

`VER_SUITE_SECURITY_APPLICANCE` = This is a version of Windows Appliance Edition.

Comment: Some flags are described here: [OSVERSIONINFOEX Structure](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724833(VS.85).aspx). However, the page describes other flags, but not these three.

Comment: [wayback machine](https://web.archive.org/web/20090414094022/http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd419805.aspx) for those who are curious